# Unable to use listOf(), hashMapOf(), mutableListOf() and other function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting below error when I am trying to use listOf(), hashMapOf(), mutableListOf() and other function in Kotlin.

**Sentence:** var moreBooks = hashMapOf<String, String>("Wilhem Tell" to "Schiller")

**Error:** Unresolved reference: hashMapOf

I have tired Invalidate Cache/Restart, still not working.
Earlier this used to work.

Please help

Comment: check your kotlin runtime and plugin version to be the last version.

Comment: can you try run your project directly? i had met this error before, but my project can run properly.i think it's an Android Studio bug.

Comment: Check if Kotlin has been configured for the project. And show the build.gradle if the Kotlin has already been configured and still you are having same issue.

Comment: Check the scope of this code. Do you write it in some class(e.g. activity), method

Comment: Make sure you have the kotlin stdlib in your project dependencies.